# How to disable MenuStrip MaximizeBox

Tags: c#, winforms

How can i disable the `MaximizeBox` of `MenuStrip` when `isMidContaine = true` of the main form. I want it to be disable not to hide `ControlBox` of the form as i read in some solutions.

```
    private void Show_Form_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.MdiParent = this;
        f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        f.Show();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You can't disable it.  Only one MDI child window can ever be maximized, it will forcibly be restored when you switch to another child.  Good bit of visible flicker when it juggles the children.  Just don't use MDI when you want this kind of windowing model, all you really need are docked usercontrols.

Comment: if i change MaximizeBox = false for the form and show it for the first time the maximizebox be enable and when i click on minimizebox and click on maximizebox of form the maximizebox be disable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void Show_Form_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.MdiParent = this;

    f.Show();

    // Disable maximize box
    f.MaximizeBox = false;
    f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: if i change MaximizeBox = false for the form and show it for the first time the maximizebox be enable and when i click on minimizebox and click on maximizebox of form the maximizebox be disable

Comment: That may depends on f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; Try to move it down, after f.MaximizeBox = false;